# Can I hook up pressurized hydrogen to a gas piston engine and have it work as is?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, automotive-engineering

I am looking to try some type of hydrogen conversion to get better gas mileage but also want to work on something new to burn some extra time.

I was mainly looking to see if I could power the entire car with a hydrogen combustion engine alone.

I am not an engineer or car person so sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: Short answer, no. Sorry

Comment: The necessary volume for hydrogen pressure bottles will be much larger than the gas tank to provide the same energy as the gas tank.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, and common, for the cases of both propane and natural gas. The pressurized tank is connected to a pressure regulator that works just like a scuba regulator, which sits where the carburetor was on the engine. When the piston goes down and creates a suction in the intake, the regulator opens up a bit and injects some gas into the intake manifold, then shuts until the next suction phase.

This setup requires some adjustments to guarantee the correct gas/air mixture for best performance, but that is not hard to do, and propane/natural gas conversion kits can be bought commercially right now.

Hydrogen conversions are possible in principle but not yet available in the market because there is no cheap source of H2, no distribution infrastructure in place for it, and no solution yet to the problem of safe, light, and inexpensive extrahigh-pressure H2 storage tanks for mobile use.

Comment: Do you have a link to such a set that uses a simple regulator for fuel delivery?

CNG has never been very popular here (Germany), but LPG (propane / butane) has, and the conversion kits use electromagnetic injectors through an extra control unit.

Comment: I do not, sorry- NN